# Number formatting in Elevation Profile in Print Composer for QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, distance, units, elevation-profile

I have created the following Elevation Profile in QGIS based on a DEM featuring its distance in metres.
[image]

As you can see, the distance axis displays the values in metres, which, for the sake of the styling of the whole graph, is pretty unconvenient.

I believe it is a rather simple request but I have been looking around the item properties up and down and I cannot find a way to "translate" these units to, for example, kilometres.

Is it even possible to change the label units? If not, is there any relatively simple workaround to solve this? Or perhaps it is a feature request to be considered on QGIS Github for the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the QGIS version you are working with. since 3.32 you can choose the distance units (kilometers, miles...). So no need for a feature request, it is already done...

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Updated my QGIS version and it works like a charm.

Comment: However, I have just spotted that this new feature of editing the labels only works with the Distance but not with the Elevation. Weird.